# Google Cloud Endpoints - generating documentation from discovery document

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it a best practice to use the Cloud Endpoints generated JSON discovery document as a basis for your developer community API docs? If not, what other methods are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to generate documentation for API consumers, a structured document describing the API is probably a great starting point ;)